# Reverse Sort Alphabetically

Tags: arrays, sorting, vbscript

I'm trying to sort a text file (CSV file) by Z-A using VBScript.
My text File looks like:

```
ZYUIP, ALGORITHM,TESTING,\ ,TABLE1
```

I wanted to order the CSV file from Z-A but I'm blocked to put the CSV file into arrays.

This is the code to order an array by Z-A:

```
ArrayOfTerms = Array("B","A","C","D")

For a = UBound(ArrayOfTerms) - 1 To 0 Step -1
    For j= 0 To a
         If ArrayOfTerms(j)<ArrayOfTerms(j+1) Then
            temp = ArrayOfTerms(j+1)
            ArrayOfTerms(j+1) = ArrayOfTerms(j)
            ArrayOfTerms(j) = temp
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Your csv file has bullet points? Is it supposed to have plusses in it and SO is just formatting it incorrectly?

Comment: My CSV hasn't have bullet points. I will correct my question

Comment: Do you want to sort the fields of each row alphabetically? Or do you want to sort the rows of the CSV alphabetically? In case of the latter: by which column?

Comment: Hello I put my solution below. Only by the first column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot download the .Net Framework. This is my solution (not optimize) to sort a CSV File from Z to A:

```
'---------------------------------------
'  Load a CSV File into a VBScript Array
'----------------------------------------
Function CSVArray(CSVFile)

   comma = ","
   quote = Chr(34)

   colMax  = -1

   rowCount     = -1
   Set inCsvSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
   Set inCsv    = inCsvSys.OpenTextFile(CSVFile,"1",True)
   Do While Not inCsv.AtEndOfStream
     rowCount = rowCount + 1
     Redim Preserve inRow(rowCount)
     inRow(rowCount) = inCsv.ReadLine
   Loop
   inCsv.Close

   For r = 0 to rowCount

     csvRecord = inRow(r)
     colNum = -1
     charPos = 0
     cellComplete = True

     Do While charPos < Len(csvRecord)

       If (cellComplete = True) Then
         colNum       = colNum + 1
         cellPos      = 0
         cellQuoted   = False
         cellComplete = False
         If colNum > colMax Then
           colMax = colNum
           Redim Preserve cellArray(rowCount,colMax)
         End If              
       End If

       charPos = charPos + 1
       cellPos = cellPos + 1
       charVal = Mid(csvRecord, charPos, 1)
       If (charVal = quote) Then
         If (cellPos = 1) Then
           cellQuoted = True
           charVal    = ""
         Else
           Select Case Mid(csvRecord, charPos+1, 1)
           Case quote
             charPos = charPos + 1
           Case comma
             charPos = charPos + 1
             cellComplete = True 
           End Select
         End If
       ElseIf (charVal = comma) And (cellQuoted = False) Then
         cellComplete = True
       End If
       If (cellComplete = False) Then
         cellArray(r,colNum) = cellArray(r,colNum)&charVal
       End If

     Loop

   Next
   CSVArray = cellArray
 End Function



csv = CSVArray("\\Ad.ing.net\wps\BE\D\UD\002001\D-JS15GY\Desktop\migrate_RA\externalfiles.csv")

Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile=objFSO.CreateTextFile("\\Ad.ing.net\wps\BE\D\UD\002001\D-JS15GY\Desktop\migrate_RA\externalfiles2.csv",2,true)

'------------------------------
'Order the CSV File from Z to A 
'------------------------------

For a = UBound(csv,1) - 1 To 0 Step -1
   for j= 0 to a
    if csv(j,0)<csv(j+1,0) then 
    temp=csv(j+1,0)
    csv(j+1,0)=csv(j,0)
        csv(j,0)=temp

    End If  
Next 

Next 

For j = 0 to Ubound(csv,1) 

    objFile.WriteLine csv(j,0)

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ArrayList.Sort from the .Net framework. Items have to be entered one by one.

```
Dim ArrayList : Set ArrayList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

'Add your items here:
ArrayList.Add "B" : ArrayList.Add "A" : ArrayList.Add "C" : ArrayList.Add "D"

ArrayList.Sort
ArrayList.Reverse
```